# How do I detect when modal title bar is done blinking with WndProc?

Tags: vb.net, modal-dialog, titlebar, wndproc

I have a VB.net MDI app that contains a modal window (normal window shown as modal).  I have a custom title bar button that disappears if the user clicks outside the modal area.

Normally, clicking off a modal will cause the system to beep and then flash the title bar of the modal window.

I want to know how to detect when the flashing is complete (using WndProc if possible) so I can redraw the custom button.

Anyone know how this could be done?  Thanks!

Comment: You can't find out.  And Lord, don't make it important that you do.

Comment: Could you explain that comment, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had the WndProc(m) line in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I believe your window should be receiving a WM_NCPAINT message when the frame needs to repaint.

Comment: I already tried the following, and none of them occur after the blink:  WM_ACTIVATE, WM_SIZE, WM_SYNCPAINT, WM_NCCREATE, WM_NCPAINT, WM_NCACTIVATE, WM_NCHITTEST, WM_PAINT, WM_APPCOMMAND